# Cross-platform and cross-language client/server application connectivity

Tags: java, c++, c, tcp

I've been searching on the Internet for an answer to this question but I couldn't find any relevant answers to my exact question.

The thing is: imagine that I have a server that is on a 32bit Linux and written in C. Then I have a client application that connects to that server and it is run on Windows 64bit and the client is written in Java. Now when these two communicate, wouldn't there be a problem?

Java char types are 2 bytes and C char types are 1 byte. From what I am also reading, some Java chars could be even 1 byte and that's the default memory allocated for the char. If I am to send chars to the server, wouldn't there be a problem?

In a more general manner, how would I design a communication protocol on top of TCP/UDP that is independent of the type sizes of different OS and programming languages? How will I send the data over the network? As chars, integers, array of something, objects???

Feel free to include any and all articles, SO questions and other resources that you think are very relevant to my question.

Comment: The Java client should not send or receive characters, it should send and receive a *byte stream* that it can convert from/to a character stream if needed.

Comment: What?  Just think about it for a bit.  You connect up to all sorts of sites on the net, yes?  You ever seen an error 'server is wrong OS' or 'server CPU width is wrong'?   No, so....

Comment: I think you have to send it in bytes. Convert all datatypes into bytes and send them over TCP/IP.

Comment: This is why we have *protocols*. They're defined in a platform-independent way. Fixed size integers stored in network by order, for example.

Comment: Okay. I have to send some text from java to the server. Then I convert it to bytes and send it to the C server. But I receive 128 bytes which represent only 64 chars because Java used 2 bytes for each char (let's say that this is the case). How do I handle that?

Comment: C can use "wide" characters too, and has a set of library functions to handle them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character

Comment: What happens when some chars don't use 2 bytes? Definition for char size in java: ``In fact many encodings only reserve 1 byte for every character (or use 1 byte for the most common characters)``

Comment: Write up an example that actually demonstrates problem. eg java sends data and c receives and misunderstands it, then people can propose concrete solutions that fix that problem. There are too many possible correct and incorrect ways to design a protocol to deal in the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

This was all solved a long time with RPC (remote procedure call) and XDR (external data representation). See [rfc4506](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506.html) on xdr, and this [Sun](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-1435/6m7rrfn6r/index.html) document on rpc and xdr, and this [rpcgen tutorial](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node34.html), and `man rpc`, `man xdr`.

Obviously, these are described for use by C.

Comment: Not to mention XML-RPC and JSONRPC which use the respective text-based formats to do the same thing.